# Sorting Values within Hash (with Sphinx facets)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-1.8

I am using Sphinx to return a hash of facets. The hash returned is like so:

```
{:brand=>{"C Brand"=>170, "A Brand"=>17, "B Brand"=>160}, :store=>{"B Store"=>95, "C Store"=>1, "A Store"=>9}}
```

The hash contains the name of the store/brand, along with the amount of products associated with them. I need the values within the hash to be ordered by the store/brand names, like so:

```
{:brand=>{"A Brand"=>170, "B Brand"=>17, "C Brand"=>160}, :store=>{"A Store"=>9, "B Store"=>95, "C Store"=>1}}
```

I have read a lot into sorting hashes, but I cannot seem to get the right method to work.

I am running ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: I edited my answer for Ruby 1.8.7.  Since you are using an old version of the language, be sure to mention that in all your questions.

Comment: Thanks David, I will be sure to mention that in future.

Answer (score 2):

To sort a hash by its keys in Ruby 1.9, do:

```
sorted_hash = Hash[unsorted_hash.sort]
```

Since you are using Ruby 1.8.7 though, you'll have to do something like this:

```
sorted_array_of_pairs = unsorted_hash.sort
```

or just sort it when it is time to iterate:

```
unsorted_hash.sort.each do |k, v|
   # ...
end
```

Comment: It does work when I iterate, but putting sort in the view doesnt seem like the 'rails way'... I'd ideally like the logic to be in the model.

Comment: Then you need to choose a different data structure for sending data from the model to the view.  Hashes in Ruby 1.8.7 are not ordered.  You could call the `sort` method on the hash to get an array of key-value pairs, sort that, and the pass that to the model.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is an error in your expected result, it should be `{:brand=>{"A Brand"=>17, "B Brand"=>160, "C Brand"=>170}, :store=>{"A Store"=>9, "B Store"=>95, "C Store"=>1}}`

Regarding the code:

```
a = {:brand=>{"C Brand"=>170, "A Brand"=>17, "B Brand"=>160}, :store=>{"B Store"=>95, "C Store"=>1, "A Store"=>9}}
a.each {|k,v| a[k] = Hash[v.sort]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you are right to notice that I neglected to change the numbers when I wrote the question, I have updated that now! Unfortunately this method does not work in ruby 1.8.7, do you know how I can get this to work?

Comment: no, I am just doing my first steps in Ruby and even did not know that that won't work in older versions :)

Answer (score 0):

If your hashes are not too big, and performance is not really an issue, you could still convert your hash to an array, sort the array, and then convert it back to an hash (or OrderedHash is you're using ruby < 1.9). It's a bit naive, but at least you can move on, focus on something else, and come back to this later, when it becomes an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
h = {:brand=>{"C Brand"=>170, "A Brand"=>17, "B Brand"=>160}, :store=>{"B Store"=>95, "C Store"=>1, "A Store"=>9}}
h.each{|k,v| h[k] = Hash[v.sort]}
```

You need Ruby 1.9 for this to work.

Comment: It is this sort of thing I am looking for, but alas I am running ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: Since you're using rails, you can use ActiveSupport::OrderedHash that guarantees the preservation of insertion order

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, in the end I went with...

```
hash.map{ |key,values| [ key, values.sort_by {|x| x.to_s.sort} ] }
```

The `.to_s` was needed because certain brand/store names were empty strings, and it could sort integers.